# i am trying to animate my div ticker using jquery but it showing undefined function animateMargin()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var top = 0;
                function animateMargin() {
                    if (top == -180) {
                        top = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        top = top - 90;

                    }
                    $('.ticker').animate({'margin-top':top+'px'},500);

                }

                marginInterval = setInterval('animateMargin', 5000);
                $('.ticker').hover(function () {
                    clearInterval(marginInterval);
                },
                function () {
                    marginInterval = setInterval('animateMargin()', 5000);
                });    
});
```

### html

```
<div class="ticker">
<h1>test 1</h1>
<h1>test 2</h1>
<h1>test 3</h1>
</div>
```

### css

```
.ticker{ }
```

question:

i m trying to animate my div top position. 0px then -90px then -180px when .ticker class margin-top is -180px then again it comes back to 0px and so. on.  help me out.

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/ytJ8Y/)

Comment: `setInterval(animateMargin,5000)`

Comment: not worked pls check my js code. correct or nt??

Comment: you want it animate regulary on hover

Comment: @user2633451 Have you you read my comment, because it works...

Comment: no on hover animation stops. i want to animate div regularly

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `setInterval(animateMargin,5000)`

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var top = 0;

    function animateMargin() {
        if (top == -180) {
            top = 0;
        } else {
            top = top - 90;

        }
        $('.ticker').animate({
            'margin-top': top + 'px'
        }, 500);

    }

    marginInterval = setInterval(animateMargin, 5000);
    $('.ticker').hover(function () {
        clearInterval(marginInterval);
    },

    function () {
        marginInterval = setInterval(animateMargin, 5000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUkq8/

Answer (score 0):

Put the function and variables outside of your `.ready()` call and set the interval correctly:

```
var top = 0;
var marginInterval;

$(document).ready(function(){
  marginInterval = setInterval(animateMargin, 5000);

  $('.ticker').hover(function () {
    clearInterval(marginInterval);
  });
});

function animateMargin() {
  if (top == -180) {
    top = 0;
  }
  else {
    top = top - 90;
  }
  $('.ticker').animate({'margin-top':top+'px'},500);
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2eZ/)

Answer (score 0):

check this:)

```
      http://jsfiddle.net/KgZkg/
```

script:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){    
            var top = 0;
            function animateMargin() {
                if (top == -180)  {
                    top = 0;
                                  }
                else 
                                 {
                    top = top - 90;
                                 }
                $('.ticker').animate({'margin-top':top+'px'},500);
                                      }
                marginInterval = setInterval(animateMargin, 500);

                $('.ticker').mouseenter(function () {
                clearInterval(marginInterval);
                                                  });    

                 $('.ticker').mouseleave(function () {
                 marginInterval = setInterval(animateMargin, 500);
                                                     });    

          });
```